# HTTP сервер java

Tags: java, android

Вот такой код есть. Нашел его на habrahabr. По идее после запуска приложения по ссылке localhost:8081 должна открыться хтмл страница  `<html><body><h1>Hello from Habrahabr</h1></body></html>`
но ничего не происходит, наверно я чего то не понимаю. Подскажите, в чем может быть дело? Интернет в манифесте прописал

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8081);
        while (true) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.err.println("Client accepted");
            new Thread(new SocketProcessor(s)).start();
        }
    }

    private static class SocketProcessor implements Runnable {

        private Socket s;
        private InputStream is;
        private OutputStream os;

        private SocketProcessor(Socket s) throws Throwable {
            this.s = s;
            this.is = s.getInputStream();
            this.os = s.getOutputStream();
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                readInputHeaders();
                writeResponse("<html><body><h1>Hello from Habrahabr</h1></body></html>");
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                /*do nothing*/
            } finally {
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    /*do nothing*/
                }
            }
            System.err.println("Client processing finished");
        }

        private void writeResponse(String s) throws Throwable {
            String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                    "Server: YarServer/2009-09-09\r\n" +
                    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                    "Content-Length: " + s.length() + "\r\n" +
                    "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
            String result = response + s;
            os.write(result.getBytes());
            os.flush();
        }

        private void readInputHeaders() throws Throwable {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while(true) {
                String s = br.readLine();
                if(s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Наверное код просто не исполняется. Во всяком случае в андроиде метод `main` нигде не используется. Попробуйте вызвать его явно в методе `onCreate`. Также, возможно, надо проверить что есть разрешение на доступ к интернету в манифесте

Comment: в onCreate я прописал main()  но оно подчеркивается и предлагает создать  метод main

Comment: Наверное вы не передали туда аргументы. Попробуйте `null` передать. Т.е. `main(null)`

Comment: Да, но локал хост по прежнему не открывает страницу

Comment: Вы так и не сказали есть ли в манифесте разрешение на интернет

Comment: Есть, я писал об этом в вопросе

Comment: Других идей у меня нет. Может стоит вот этот пример попробовать: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: "локал хост по прежнему не открывает страницу", а как вы это проверяете?